# Django - Create object if field not in database

Tags: python, django

I want to create an object only if there's no other object with the same ID already in the database. The code below would create the same item if one the parameters below like the State was modified.

```
returns = Return.objects.all()
for ret in returns:
    obj, created = Return.objects.get_or_create(ItemID="UUID", 
                          ItemName="Hodaddy", State="Started")
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_or_create` works off **all** the arguments provided to find the object.

What you need to do instead is use the special [`defaults` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to provide the new value for a field that you don't want to filter on.

In your case, you only want the UUID field to be unique, and so you provide the other two members as defaults.

```
obj, created = Return.objects.get_or_create(ItemID="UUID", 
               defaults={ItemName:"Hodaddy", State:"Started"})
```

Then you can make further decisions based on the value of `created`. I am not sure why you're iterating over all the Returns in the original question?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the id, you can query for it:

In your question, you have:

```
returns = Return.objects.all()
for ret in returns:
   return_in_database = Return.objects.filter(ItemId="UUID").exists()
   if not return_in_database:
       obj, created = Return.objects.get_or_create(ItemID="UUID", 
                      ItemName="Hodaddy", State="Started")
       obj.save()
```

This can be done as:

```
if not Return.objects.filter(ItemId="UUID").exists():
    obj, created = Return.objects.get_or_create(ItemID="UUID", 
                      ItemName="Hodaddy", State="Started")
    obj.save()
```

As you can see, I've removed the for loop, as you were not using the variable `ret` anywhere, so no need to iterate over all Return objects. The above is functionally equivalent to what you had. :)

OR:

You can write your own manager with a create_or_update method inside your models.py

```
class ReturnManager(models.Manager): 
    def create_or_update(self, **kwargs):
        new_return = Return(**kwargs)
        existing = Return.objects.filter(ItemId=new_returns.ItemID).first()
        if existing:
            new_return.pk  = existing.pk
            new_return.id = existing.id
        new_return.save()
        return new_return
```

You would then assign this to your Return model

```
class Return(model.Models):
    # your object fields here

    objects = ReturnManager()
```

Comment: Hi Neelik, thanks for both answers. I'm proposing some changes to the first answer and mark it as correct

Comment: Ok, what changes would you like me to make?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the param in the query, to just constraint the object lookup on `ItemID`. Once, a new object is returned you can update the `ItemName` and `State`

```
obj, created = Return.objects.get_or_create(ItemID="UUID")
if created:
    obj.ItemName="<item-name>"
    obj.State="<Started>"
    obj.save()
```